# Spark: How to use Avro schema to create a dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, avro, apache-spark-dataset, avsc

I have a set of avro files saved in aws S3 with known schema defined in a .avsc file. Is there a way to create a dataset of objects in spark with the schema defined?

The schema look like:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "NameRecord",
  "namespace" : "com.XXX.avro",
  "doc" : "XXXXX",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "Metadata",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "MetaNameRecord",
      "doc" : "XXXX",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "id",
        "type" : "int"
      }, {
        "name" : "name",
        "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
        "default" : null
      }]
}
```

I would like to create a dataset of NameRecord: Dataset[NameRecord]

Answer (score 1):

Avro object files, by definition, already have a schema within them.

Should just need to do this

```
val df = spark.read.format("avro").load("s3://path")
df.schema
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html

Comment: Dataframe will give us a dataset of [Row]. We need to perform complex functions on each of the record so that a Dataset[NameRecord] would be ideal to use the schema pojo and get the structured fields easily.

Comment: You should be able to use `load().as()` to give it a specific schema